# Google Appengine regex variable passing

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

how can i pass the "xxxxxx" part to the messages function ?

```
("/user/xxxxxx/messsages/?",messages)
```

this is my code.but it pass "user/xxxxx" .

```
....
class messages (webapp2.RequestHandler):        
def get(self,username):
....
....
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                           ("/user/(\w+)/messages/?",messages),
                           ], debug=True )
```

i just want the "xxxxxx" part . what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `r''` on the regular expression:

```
(r'/user/(\w+)/messages/?',messages)
```

Because you left it off, `"/user/(\w+)/messages/?"` became `'/user/(\\w+)/messages/?'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the webapp2 URL template. That way you can use your regular expression and pass it to your handler as a kwargs.

[webapp2 URL Template](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#the-url-template)

```
class messages (webapp2.RequestHandler):        
    def get(self,username):
        ...

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                       ("/user/<id:\w+>/messages/?",messages),
                       ], debug=True )
```